# Amazon Web Services (AWS) architecture

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS and would like to get an opinion on this before I dive in.

I have a small web based business built on asp.net and a SQL Database.  I'd like to move it over to AWS.  I'm still trying to get familiar with AWS and have been reading lots on it.

Should I:
1) host my database on RDS
2) host the website (asp.net) files on S3
3) run the application on EC2 instances

Is that pretty standard?? I understand how to do 1 and 2 but not sure how to link #3.   If that's even the route I should be taking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the most convenient way to do your hosting application is to use **AWS Elastic Beanstalk**. It makes things a lot easy for you and has support for .NET

Elastic Beanstalk makes is easy to setup the RDS, EC2, Load Balancer (ELB), mark static files for fast-serving etc. Code deployment and version management is also very easy.

More Details here:
[Creating and Deploying AWS Elastic Beanstalk Applications in .NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.html)

Additionally, if you need further page load speed, you can host the static files on AWS S3 plus AWS Cloudfront. You can use this route to keep the static files (images, JS, CSS etc). Read more here: [Hosting a Static Website on Amazon S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html).

I have written a blog post recently to explain this approach a bit. [Easy webapp on AWS](http://notingon.com/2014/02/25/easy-webapp-on-aws/)

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on your specifics, but here are some of my thoughts:

1 - hosting your sql db on RDS is fine, it is equally fine to host your database directly on your ec2 instance, perhaps even using the free version of sql server (sql express). For a low to medium low traffic site. For such a site it will work just fine and its not a bad way to start. If you don't want to manage the DB yourself, and you are OK with the extra cost, there is nothing wrong with going with RDS (probably technically a better solution); you also have the good option of starting with a local SQL Sever db on your ec2 instance an upgrade only if/when you need or want to.

2 You can't host your asp.net based website on S3, S3 could host a static website but asp.net is not an option; asp.net needs a back end server to serve it, so S3 would not be appropriate. You could however serve *some* of you assets from S3, i.e. images, css files and JavaScript files; you could also push those assets around the world using their CDN Cloudfront - that would be an appropriate and good use of S3 for an asp.net website.

3 If you are using asp.net, you pretty much are going to have to run your website on an ec2 instance if you plan on using aws...there isn't an alternative; they don't offer a shared hosting plan (ala discountasp.net).

Comment: Thank you.  That's basically what I've set up so far on AWS (database and website located all on one EC2 m1.small instance).  However, the website is really slow.  Slower than where I currently have it hosted (Arvixe on a business class server $37/month).  So I was thinking that maybe there is a better option.

Comment: Its worth trying two things; move the db to RDS, upgrade from a small instance to medium or large. Running a small instance with sql on the same machine is probably pushing it. I do it on a large instance w/no problems however.